# useNavigate hook not working in react 18.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three pages, one for a form, another one for a thank you page, and the last one for the admin. The form page triggers an event that calls useNavigate function with the state. but when I submit the form it doesn't navigate from the form page to thank you page although all data are sent to the database. I am using `"react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0"` and `"react-router-dom": "^6.6.2"`.
**Below is the code I am using:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import supabase from '../config/supabase'
import src from '../assets/figo.jpg'

const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    const handleChange=()=>{
        setisChecked(!isChecked);
    }
    const [isChecked, setisChecked]=useState(false);
    
    const [fname,setFname] = useState('')
    const [lname,setLname] = useState('')
    const [age,setAge] = useState('')
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
    const [phone,setPhone] = useState('')
   
    const [formError, setFormError]=useState(null)

    const handleSubmit=async(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault()

     if(!fname || !lname || !age || !email ||!phone ){
        setFormError('please fill all the fields')
        return
     }
     const {data,error} = await supabase 
     .from('profiles')
     .insert([{fname,lname,age,email,phone}])

     if(error){
      console.log(error)
      setFormError('check internet connection')
     }
     if(data){
      console.log(data)
      setFormError(null)
      navigate('/thank')
     }
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="h3">
            <h3>FIGO MARATHON REGISTRATION FORM 2023</h3>
            </div>
            <img src={src} alt=""/>
            <h4>Location:Uhuru stadium, Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</h4>
            <h4>Race Dates: 12/3/2023</h4>
            <h4>Time: 6am to 1pm</h4>

            <div class="h3">
            <h3>Participants Details</h3>
            </div>

            <label htmlFor='fname'>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" value={fname}
            onChange={(e)=>setFname(e.target.value)}
            />

            <label htmlFor='lname'>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" value={lname}
            onChange={(e)=>setLname(e.target.value)}
            />

            <label htmlFor='age'>Age</label>
            <input type="number" id="age" value={age}
            onChange={(e)=>setAge(e.target.value)}
            />

            <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" value={email}
            onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />

             <label htmlFor='phone'>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" value={phone}
            onChange={(e)=>setPhone(e.target.value)}
            />

            <div class="h3">
            <h3>Waiver & Release</h3>
            </div>

            <h5>Weaver health questions</h5>
            <div class="ri">
            <input class="ro" type="checkbox" id="confirm"
            checked={isChecked}
             onChange={handleChange}/>
            <p>I confirm that i am in good shape,health and condition.</p>
            </div>

             <div class="ri">
            <input class="ro" type="checkbox" id="medical"
            checked={isChecked} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <p>I don't have any medical condition or medical history that will affect my participation in this event.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="ri">
            <input class="ro" type="checkbox" id="follow"
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={handleChange}/>
            <p>I will follow the rule and regulations of the road race event.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="ri">
            <input class="ro" type="checkbox" id="road"
            checked={isChecked}
             onChange={handleChange}/>
                <p>I acknowledge that this road race requires physical activity and rhere are possible risks and danger</p>
            </div>

            <div class="ri">
            <input class="ro" type="checkbox" id="reg"
            checked={isChecked}
             onChange={handleChange}/>
                <p>I confirm that all information in this registration form is accurate and true</p>
            </div>

            <button>Submit</button>
            {formError && (<p>{formError}</p>)}
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by passing all the data i initialized instead of data

```
 const handleSubmit=async(e)=>{
 e.preventDefault()

 if(!fname || !lname || !age || !email ||!phone ||!relate ||!emphone ||!team ||!trans ){
    setFormError('please fill all the fields')
    return
 }
 const {data,error} = await supabase 
 .from('profiles')
 .insert([{fname,lname,age,email,phone,relate,emphone,team,trans}])

 if(error){
  console.log(error)
  setFormError('check internet connection or check the transaction message')
 }
 if(fname,lname,age,email,phone,relate,emphone,team,trans){
  console.log(fname,lname,age,email,phone,relate,emphone,team,trans)
  setFormError(null)
  navigate("/thank")
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It seems in supabase version 2 we need to add select() method after insert() in order to get back the data we just inserted into table (It doesn't send the data back by default), this worked for me:

```
 const {data,error} = await supabase 
     .from('profiles')
     .insert([{fname,lname,age,email,phone}])
     .select()

 if(error){
  console.log(error)
  setFormError('check internet connection or check the transaction message')
 }
 if(data){
  console.log(data)
  setFormError(null)
  navigate("/thank")
 }
```